# How to fetch file from smb server in to android mobile

Tags: java, android, file-transfer, smb

I tried to transfer the file from smb server to android mobile.its showing Error in setDataAndType(uri,String)[Error: No Activity found to handle intent].How to solve it.

Comment: I refer this link [link](http://www.lysesoft.com/products/andsmb/intent.html)

Comment: see this: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/android-sambha-jsifs-file-sharing.html

Comment: i refer that code also .. its getting NtlmPasswordAuthentication class file missing #AviLevin